# How to react on actions (events) in real time in Tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, label, real-time

I´d like to create a program which will react on actions by user in real time. For example there will be three `Labels`. And when user clicks on one, I want to recolor the border to a different color and the user should be able to "type" a (single) number in this `Label`. I know about the Entry widget, but Labels are suitable for the whole application.

Thank you for any answers

Comment: You appear to be asking two questions at the same time, and neither one is fully-specified or makes sense to me. Could you clarify?

Comment: I think it's possible to make an Entry look like a Label. But like delnan says, I don't really understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to answer precisely, but to specifically address each individual point:

- Yes, it's possible to "react .. in real time" -- whenever an event is detected it will be acted upon as soon as possible.
- Yes, it's possible to color the border of a widget when an event is detected
- Yes, it's possible to type into a label. Though, obviously, the behavior is unusual and may not be what you expect.

I suspect none of those help you solve your real problem, but I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: All right, to be more specific. I´ll try to simplify this. There will be one Label widget. In default state it´s "inactive", so whatever user does, the widget will stay without any changes. Unless user clicks on this widget. This will get the Label into an "active" state (which will be indicated by change of border color). While it stays in active state, user is able to change the content of widget (=text inside) by pressing keys . And when user clicks out of the active widget, it will get back to inactive state. That´s what I´m trying to achieve. BTW: max length of text in Label is 1 char.

Comment: @MilanSkála: why not use an entry widget? It gives you almost exactly this behavior. You can easily change the border and background colors to make it look identical to a label.

Comment: Because the whole application already works fine (except this problem) and it would be pretty difficult to "remake" it for Entries. Plus I don´t want blinking cursor :). But if you have an idea how to remove blinking cursor, it could be fine.

Comment: OK, I solved the blinking cursor with insertontime=0, now only changing border color left. Is it necessary to create an event with function or is there some parameter of Entry which will change the border color after clicking on it?